How to add retry capability to a tower service in rust?
I have implemented this RateLimiter Struct:
pub struct RateLimiter<S, T>
where
    S: Service<T>,
    S::Response: Send + 'static,
    S::Error: Into<APIError> + Into<Box<dyn StdError + Send + Sync + 'static>> + Send + Sync + 'static,
    S::Future: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    service: Buffer<T, ResponseFuture<<S as Service<T>>::Future>>,
}

impl<S, T> RateLimiter<S, T>
where
    S: Service<T> + Send + 'static,
    S::Response: Send + 'static,
    S::Error: Into<APIError> + Into<Box<dyn StdError + Send + Sync + 'static>> + Send + Sync + 'static,
    S::Future: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    pub fn new(service: S, rate_limit: usize, buffer_size: usize, concurrency_limit: usize) -> Result<Self, APIError> {
        let rate_limit_u64: u64 = rate_limit
            .try_into()
            .map_err(|_| APIError::Other("Invalid rate limit value".to_string()))?;

        let rate_limited_service: Buffer<T, ResponseFuture<<S as Service<T>>::Future>> = ServiceBuilder::new()
            .buffer(buffer_size)
            .concurrency_limit(concurrency_limit)
            .rate_limit(rate_limit_u64, Duration::from_secs(1))
            .service(service);

        Ok(RateLimiter {
            service: rate_limited_service,
        })
    }


    pub async fn call(&mut self, request: T) -> Result<S::Response, APIError> {
        self.service.call(request).await.map_err(|e| APIError::from(e))
    }
}

I want to add retry capability to it in case of failure of a request. How can I achieve this using tower?
I've spent quite a bit of time experimenting with different approaches to add retry capability to my service using Tower, but unfortunately, all my attempts have failed.

Are you aware, that there already is retry middleware implemented in tower itself? Does it satisfy your needs? Or perhaps you are trying to implement it yourself for a learning purpose?

@AleksanderKrauze yes, I'm aware of it and I mean I want to add it to my RateLimiter struct, I just can't get it to work unfortunately.
